# deploying identityserver 4 to azure app service

Tags: identityserver4, .net-core-3.1, azure-appservice

When deploying a blazor app that contains identityserver 4 to an azure app service, i get the following exception:

`Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error loading the certificate. Either the password is incorrect or the process does not have permisions to store the key in the Keyset 'DefaultKeySet'`

The certificate comes from azure keyvault and locally there are no issues.
Below the code I use to call the cert and load it into the identityserver signingcredentials:

```
var pfx = Configuration["certname"];
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pfx);
var certificate2Collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificate2Collection.Import(bytes, null, X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet);

services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddSigningCredential(certificate2Collection[0]);
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Same problem after updating to IS4. The cert worked fine before the upgrade. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of searching gave me the answer.

I needed to do 2 things.

First I needed to add the certificate in the service app on azure:
[image: azure app service certificate]

Then in the configuration of the service app, I needed to add an application setting:
WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with the cert thumbprint as value:
[image: azure app service application settings]

After that the certificate was found without a problem.